# Drupal Twig Integer conversion not working

Tags: drupal, twig-filter

I an trying to loop x times from a integer field value.

But no matter how i format the twig-filter the field value 6 is converted to 1.
The string '6' is converted to int 1.

I have module twig tools enabled.

```
{{content.body|raw|integer}} // always 1

{% for i in range(1, content.body|raw|integer) %}
 {{ i }}
 <div class="stars"><i class="fa fa-star"></div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I cant find any docs on `integer`, but why convert it? Sending a string to the range function should work. eg `for i in range(1, content.body|raw)`

Comment: No that does not work. The loop only runs ones, no matter the value in content.body.
I fix the issue in a loop in hook_preprocess_field. But I would prefer if it could work in twig.

Answer (score 1):

Because the body is a textarea and it's raw version may include HTML, it's probably not returning a simple string value of "6", but likely something like:

```
<p>6</p>
```

The integer twig filter uses PHP's [intval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) function, which will return 1 on an object or non-empty array.

I would suggest using an Integer field to store your number instead of the body field.

Comment: Thanks for teh reply, but this have been tried with the exact same result